# Laravel global variable

Tags: php, laravel

I have a simple code that displays to the user all of his notifications received from the Database:

`$user_notifications =  DB::table('notifications')->where('user_id', $this->user->id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();`

the problem is that I have too many controllers and functions in them and I don’t want to duplicate this code everywhere, in each function and controller. How can I make the `$user_notifications` variable global and use it everywhere?

Comment: What's wrong with creating a new function or class for this piece of code?

Comment: Read about abstraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u need to create a `NotificationRepository`

```
class NotificationsRepository
{
    private Notifications $model;

    public function __construct(Notification $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function findByUserId(int $userId): Collection
    {
        return $this->model->where('user_id', $userId)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
    }
}
```

Then in Controller action add this repository by autowiring

```
class SomeController extends Controller
{
    public function someAction(NotificationRepository $repository, int $id)
    {
        $notifications = $repository->findByUserId($id);
    }
}
```

or this way, i dont know how did u use your actions

```
class SomeController extends Controller
{
    public function someAction(NotificationRepository $repository, Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
    {
        $notifications = $repository->findByUserId($request->user()->id);
    }
}
```